# How to Check if i have text in my input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a small program that will check if I have any text inside the input field ... if its a number it's easy i just do

```
cardsp.value >= 1
```

But when the input is text how can I check if there is anything in the field?

```
Name : <input id="namep" type="text" />
```

I tried to do something like that (js) but that probably the most wrong way that someone ever does

```
    var array= ["","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","m","n","l","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
function pay()  {
    namep.value 
    if(namep.value >= array.indexOf("a"), cardsp.value >= 1 , emailpa.value >= 1){

         alert('Ty For Buying a Ticket From our compeny , you will receive the Invoicing in the ' +emailpa.value);
        }

    else if(namep.value == array.indexOf(""){
            alert('Please Write Your Name');
    }

    }
```

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to check if there is any input in the text field, or if the field contains only the letters a-z?

Comment: if there is a any input in the text field

Comment: @KondukterCRO has the answer you're after :)

Comment: there is a way to do it in javascript and not Jqurey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var input=$("#namep").val();
```

or

```
var input = document.getElementById('namep').value;
```

and then check if there is something...

```
if(input.length>0)
{
 //do something. 
}
```

or

```
var inputLength = input.length;

if(inputLength>0)
{
 //do something. 
}
```

Comment: there is a way to do it in javascript ?

Comment: In your original code, you were checking against namep.value. So you can just do namep.value.length > 0

Answer (score 1):

You could check if input field contains only letters that way:

```
var letters = /^[a-z]+$/;  
if( namep.value.match(letters) ) {
  // string contains only letters.
}
```

Comment: there is a way to do it in javascript ?

Comment: only captures lowercase letters... [a-zA-Z]

Comment: @omermalka this is a javascript; Maybe /^[a-z]+$/ looks strange but it is simple regular expression. You could learn more about regular expressions and even play with them on: http://www.regexr.com/